# Methodical way to form a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a basis $(3,1,0,0,0),(0,0,7,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)$ for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ and want to extend this collection of vectors to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ is there any methodical, or algorithmic way to do this besides logically picking two linearly independent vectors to extend the set to a basis?

Comment: Are you familiar with Gram Schmidt orthogonalisation?

Comment: yea I'll have to review it, but I remember using the method we can find linearly independent vectors algorithmically

Comment: One (slow) way is to start with a known basis, such as that provided by the unit vectors $e_1,...e_5$. Then see if each is contained in the the span of the above list ($e_5$ is, trivially). If so, ignore, otherwise add to the collection. Rinse & repeat until finished.

Comment: @copper.hat You can test for all of them at once using Gaussian elimination, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way is to form a matrix with these vectors as columns, which has column space equal to $\mathbb{R}^{5}$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
3&0&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\
1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&7&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now you want to follow the method to get a basis for the column space: Figure out which are the pivot columns, and use those as a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ (note that with this setup, since your original three vectors were linearly independent, they will be pivot columns and so used as the first three vectors of the basis).